# Vehicle Registration Plate OCR

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

The final call of pyterresect is not returning an string instead its printing values of every pixel of that image only.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import  imutils
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

count = 0
for c in cnts:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
        if len(approx) == 4:  # Select the contour with 4 corners
            NumberPlateCnt = approx #This is our approx Number Plate Contour
            pl=NumberPlateCnt
            print(NumberPlateCnt)
            if(pl[0][0][1]+10>pl[2][0][1] or pl[0][0][0]+40>pl[2][0][0]):
                continue
            filter_img = image[pl[0][0][1]:pl[2][0][1],pl[0][0][0]:pl[2][0][0]]
            print("Number Plate Detected")
            cv2_imshow(filter_img)

            Number=pytesseract.image_to_string(filter_img,lang='eng')
            print("Number is :",Number)
            cv2.waitKey(0)
            cv2.drawContours(image, [NumberPlateCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

print("Final Image With Number Plate Detected")
cv2_imshow(image)

cv2.waitKey(0) #Wait for user input before closing the images displayed
```

the number i am getting here should be some string but its printing like some sort of matrix as we get when we print an image using print.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix you are getting is most probably coming from this line of your code:

```
print(NumberPlateCnt)
```

And `pytesseract.image_to_string` is just failing to identify any text on the rectangular contours you are trying to get, which means the following two lines print you an empty result:

```
Number=pytesseract.image_to_string(filter_img,lang='eng')
print("Number is :",Number)
```

Since you are iterating over the contours with the largest areas, the output should look something like this:

> Number Plate Detected
>
> Number is :
>
> [[[223 278]]
>
> [[272 279]]
>
> [[274 282]]
>
> [[224 281]]]

The "Number is: " string is just empty and the following matrix result is coming out of next iteration of contours calculation.

To fix that, you can check if the string returned by PyTesseract contains anything at all, something like this:

```
   if (len(Number)):
       print("Number is :", Number)
```

It will print Number only in case if it contains any symbols in it recognized by PyTesseract.

Comment: In this case also its printing the same matrix. but the image which i am passing to the function is only contain boundary and alphanumeric letters.

Comment: Could you share an example of image you are trying?